# View and ICollection Question

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am coverting my app from webforms to mvc, at the moment i am at a design issue (well i just dont know how to do it in mvc).

Basically my model would be something like this:

```
public class DamagedItem 
{
  public Int32 LoanId {get;set;}
  public String IdentityCode {get;set;}
  public virtual ICollection<DamagedItems> DamagedItems {get;set;}
}
```

In my controller i would like to do:

```
public ActionResult Add(DamagedItem damagedItem)
{
  //Do update logic here

}
```

Then in my view i can add to the ICollection as needed.
But, i can't do this because if i try and access the ICollection from my controller it is null.

Here is an image of when i want to do:
[image]

I just dont know how to lay it out in my view, how to i add such items to my ICollection, update the view then when i need to save i have access to what i have added from my controller?

Thanks,
Nick

Edit:

---

I was thinking of using a partial in the view and doing all the logic for the bottom half using ajax and storing it in a session variable, but i would prefer NOT to make it reliant on ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to separate: you shoud have 2 actions, which produce 2 view.

You should have LoadInformationModel classe:

```
public class LoadInformationModel 
{
  public string StudentCode { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  // etc..

  public ICollection<Damage> Type { get; set; }
}
```

corresponding action

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult LoanInformation(int id) 
{
  var loanInfo = // get data by given id..
  var model = new LoadInformationModel {
    StudentCode = loanInfo.StudentCode,
    // etc
    Type = new List<Damage> { new Damage { Value = "Damaged"}, new Damage { Value = "Damaged Again" }
  }

  return View(model);
}
```

As well as RepairDataModel class

public class RepairDataModel 
{
  public bool CoveredByWarranty { get; set; }
  public ICollection Status { get; set; }
}

And corresponding action

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Repair(int id) 
{
  // logic
  return View(model);
}
```

Your task is to create Post handler, that would save data to DB then form submitted

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult(RepairDataModel model)
{
   // save to db
   return View();
}
```

The view returned by Index() method, could be created like

```
@Html.RenderAction("LoanInformation")

@Html.RenderAction("Repair")
```

The rest depends on your desing and imagination. I hope that would give you direction.

Answer (score 0):

What I can see is only the DamagedItem lacks a contructor with values for Collection;

```
public class DamagedItem 
{
  public DamagedItem() 
  {
    DamagedItems = new List<DamagedItems>();
    DamagedItems.Add(new DamagedItem { Description = "Damaged" } );
  }

  public Int32 LoanId {get;set;}
  public String IdentityCode {get;set;}
  public virtual ICollection<DamagedItems> DamagedItems {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: The view basically has two form sections, one to save the whole DamagedEntry and another to build a list of damaged items.
So how do i fill the collection from the second form section then save it all using the first form.

I hope i am making sense..

Comment: You could say i am trying to create  Master / Detail view